# A general approach to choosing/deriving response functions?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium

I'm interested in applying some simple linear response theory to a (weakly) non-equilibrium system. For example, consider a microscopic rigid body attached to a wall at a certain point, and that this body can spin freely in circles around this fixed point. The body is subject to thermal fluctuations but it also has access to a reservoir of energy such that it can actively propel itself.

In this context, my interest is in measuring the degree to which this object violates equilibrium. My understanding is that I can, for example, test if the object is in equilibrium via the following equality:

C(f) = 2TR(f)

Where C(f) is the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function of the object's rotational velocity, R(f) is the Fourier transform of the corresponding response function, and T is temperature. Equilibrium is satisfied by equality, and some recent work has used C - 2TR as a measure of how far from equilibrium a given system is.

Here is my confusion: how do we choose, or more generally derive, the response function? I've been looking up examples in the literature and as far as I can tell, people generally consider it obvious or they have an ansatz. I'm struggling to understand how to choose/derive the response function. In particular, I'm studying active (self-propelled) particles and I want to model their response to perturbations using this framework; calculating the autocorrelation function of their velocities is straightforward, but I don't know how to begin calculating their response functions (e.g., given 3D trajectories of the particles). Would appreciate any remarks, especially if I'm off the mark on any of these basic points.